# How to assign to a variable the outputs of the method "describe"?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, analytics

good morning!

Could you help me, please, teaching me how to assign to a variable the outputs of the method "describe"?

[image]

Thanks and have a great day!

Comment: `describe()` returns an indexed dataframe.   so you can use `df_cred_pd.describe().loc["25%", "vr_tx_jrs"]`  best not to post images to SO.  Cannot reproduce from images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 25% and 50% are quantiles so you can simply use the pandas `quantile` function to get those values.

For all the information you see in `describe` output, you have functions in `pandas.DataFrame` that you can work with, e.g.:

```
count -> pandas.DataFrame.count
mean -> pandas.DataFrame.mean
std -> pandas.DataFrame.std
min -> pandas.DataFrame.min
25%, 50%, 75% or any other quantile -> pandas.DataFrame.quantile
max -> pandas.DataFrame.max
```

Answer (score 3):

`pd.DataFrame.describe` returns a dataframe, you can use loc to access each cell of a dataframe or you can calculate the stat directly.

```
import pandas as pd
from seaborn import load_dataset

df_tips =  load_dataset('tips')
print(df_tips.describe())
```

Output:

```
       total_bill         tip        size
count  244.000000  244.000000  244.000000
mean    19.785943    2.998279    2.569672
std      8.902412    1.383638    0.951100
min      3.070000    1.000000    1.000000
25%     13.347500    2.000000    2.000000
50%     17.795000    2.900000    2.000000
75%     24.127500    3.562500    3.000000
max     50.810000   10.000000    6.000000
```

Getting 25%:

```
df_tips.describe().loc['25%', 'total_bill']
#or
df_tips['total_bill'].quantile(.25)
```

Output:

```
13.3475
```

Getting 50%:

```
df_tips.describe().loc['50%', 'total_bill']
#or
df_tips['total_bill'].quantile(.50)
```

Output:

```
17.795
```